# Android Cursor _id field

Tags: android

I have a query I am running using `SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery` which is grouped and doesn't necessarily have a field I can alias as the required _id field needed by the Cursor.  Seeing that MySQL doesn't support the rowid function, is there another way around this to avoid the following exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id'` does not exist.  Also I am using a custom adapter to display these results in a ListView.

Comment: Could you post the query you are executing and give us an idea of the table structure you are querying against?

Answer (score 6):

You must be extending [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) which demand _id column.

- Add alias in database query to id

Example:

```
SELECT id _id, name, address FROM user
```

- Or if you don't need to distinct rows by id, put in query fake _id.

Example:

```
SELECT 1 _id, name, address FROM user
```

- Or extend other Adapter.